# how to run python script through mininet host without mistakes?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, mininet, ryu

I have a problem running python script via host command inside the Mininet topology code. I want run `HTTPServer.py` on `h1` and `host.py` on other hosts, so that they can send HTTP requests to `h1`. The following is my code

---

```
...Build a mininet topology...

h1 = net.get('h1')
h1.cmd('python HTTPServer.py &')
for i in ...
    ho = net.get('h%s' % i)
    ho.cmd('python host.py &')
```

---

The Mininet executed without errors and it is running these scripts. But after for a while, it does not seem to be running.

But if I run `HTTPServer.py` and `host.py` through hosts via xterm, they can run without mistakes. I don't why they do like this.

Comment: You can add error log and check it after execution.  Like this python host.py 2>error.txt &

Comment: It's not about ryu, it's a mininet problem. Ryu is just a controller, mininet handle the host and network.

Comment: No error. It just like that Httpserver does not send packets to hosts.